# how to create keyspace for cassandra using docker compose v3

Tags: cassandra, docker-compose

I am trying to create keyspace using docker-compose v3, but it is not working out, my docker-compose.yaml looks like following :

```
version: '3'
services:
  cassandra:
   image: cassandra:latest
   networks:
     - default
   ports:
     - "9042:9042"
   volumes:
     - ../compi${COMPI}/data/cassandra:/var/lib/cassandra
     - ../../sql:/compi/sql
     - ../compi${COMPI}/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/compi/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:ro


   healthcheck:
     test: ["CMD-SHELL", "[ $$(nodetool statusgossip) = running ]"]
     interval: 30s
     timeout: 10s
     retries: 5

compi:
   environment:
     - DOCKER=true
   depends_on:
     - cassandra
   links:
     - cassandra
   build:
     context: ../..
     dockerfile: ./docker.local/compi/Dockerfile
   volumes:
     - ../config:/compi/config
     - ../compi${COMPI}/log:/compi/log
     - ../compi${COMPI}/data:/compi/data

   ports:
     - "717${compi}:717${compi}"

volumes:
  data:
  config:
```

my docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.cql looks like following:

```
CREATE  KEYSPACE IF NOT EXISTS sample WITH REPLICATION = { 
  'class''SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 1 } AND DURABLE_WRITES 
  = true;
```